# ConcurrentHashMap and LibGDX Java Error

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, native-code, concurrenthashmap

Okay I just got a weird bug and I'm not knowing whether it has to do with the Java Version, with the Sourcecode or with my machine. *(I update my Java Version today!)*

Up to the Problem... I am writing a Game with Libgdx, nothing fancy till now, just some Shooting and Destroying of Objects. To destory Objects I add them to a **CopyOnWriteArrayList** and after the WorldLogic and EntityLogic are finished I delete those Objects (to prevent bugs) - works perfectly fine.

To add Objects to the scene, in this case a bullet, I call a method which adds a BodyDef and a FixtureDef to a Hashmap, this Hashmap is then iterated and the body is created from the BodyDef and FixtureDef. Code:

```
public void createBodies() {
    for (ConcurrentHashMap.Entry<BodyDef, FixtureDef> entry: bodiesToCreate.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: "+entry.getKey()+", Value: "+ entry.getValue());
        myWorld.getWorld().createBody(entry.getKey()).createFixture(entry.getValue());
        bodiesToCreate.remove(entry);
    }
}
```

The printed values are for example:

> {com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef@509dd43b=com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef@5810f29f}

Long story short: As soon as I click the left mouse button to shoot, the program freezes and I get this errorlog in the console: [Errorlog on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Tp0j0AfS)

I tried to debug, which looks like this mid debugging. Notice the strange repetition of this -> entry -> this -> entry -> this .... (looked infinite) [Debugging Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmYYj.jpg)

I'm just not experienced enough to figure out what the problem is, so I went here to ask for help. Thanks in advance SO!

Regards

Comment: Well, you have a huge line of code. Why don't you break it up and see what's not working correct? See if entry.key() is working correctly. see if you can add a fixture like that see if entry.getValue() is working ect..

Comment: I did exactly that, the values I add are correct and add fixture is correct used as well ... Working on this problem since 2 days, can't solve it.

Comment: I believe its related to the library you are using, I'm not familiar with it, but just make sure you are coding to its standards of use?  check out https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1730

Comment: What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: I don't get a stacktrace, because the error happens outside the java VM (at least that's what Java is telling me). All I got is the error log which I linked.

Comment: Faults in the box2d library from Libgdx usually result from freeing objects multiple times, or re-adding the same object multiple times.

Comment: The error log should probably be part of the question. However, the relevant part there is `Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body.jniCreateFixture(...)`. This seems to be a similar error like the one reported in http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15752&p=68074 , but this was just one of the first websearch results (I did not yet have a look at the code of this method, but it could bring some insights)

Comment: Is it safe to remove an element from a hashmap while you are iterating over it? Why not just clear the hashmap after the loop has finished?

Comment: It is, as this is a concurrentHashmap. I just solved the problem, it had something to to with buggy spawncode. I fixed it with the approach I mentioned here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243532/libgdx-stop-body-from-taking-properties-of-previously-deleted-body)